# Trigonemetric Functions Exam Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The sketch below shows the function y = f(x) and a transformation, labelled C. Write down the equation of the translated curve C in function form.

[image]

How I found out the function:
[image]

But it says the answer is -2f(2x).

What did I do wrong? Thank You and Help is Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot to reflect your graph about the $x$-axis. Hence, your answer differ by a negative sign.

Consider the region just after $y$-axis, notice that the graph decreases rather than increases.

Comment: But doesn't the graph decrease because of the f(2x)?

Comment: $f(2x)$ just shrink the graph is the horizontal direction, it doesn't reflect the graph.